# Fetch request in react native doesn't get full webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-native, fetch, google-translate

I'm trying to get the translated text from "https://translate.google.com/#en/sv/hello%20my%20name%20is%20mia" in my react native app. The problem I'm running into is that the returned html isn't the full webpage and is instead what is rendered when you click "view page source". This for some reason doesn't have the translated text in it even though the translated text is seen using "inspect" and is on the webpage itself.

How do I fetch the full webpage with the javascript rendered?

```
googletranslate() {
return fetch('https://translate.google.com/#en/sv/hello%20my%20name%20is%20mia', {async:false})
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    console.log(responseText);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

This is what it currently returns in the html file:

```
... <span id=result_box class="short_text"></span> ...
```

And I need it to return this:

```
... <span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="sv"><span class="">hej jag heter mia</span> ...
```

Comment: From memory, Google does not allow its public sites to be scraped. You should instead use the appropriate API ~ https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Comment: @Phil None of the packages I've tried work with react native. How can I get the google translate api to work with a react native mobile app?